# What is the fastest way to convert pyspark column into a python list?

Tags: python, list, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have a large pyspark data frame but used a small data frame like below to test the performance. I know three ways of converting the pyspark column into a list but non of them are as fast as how spark jobs are run. What is the best and fastest way of creating a python list from pyspark data frame column?

```
Dataframe:-

from pyspark.sql import Row

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    Row(a=1, b=4., c='GFG1'),
    Row(a=2, b=8., c='GFG2'),
    Row(a=4, b=5., c='GFG3')
]) 

method 1:-
list1=[]
for row_iterator in df.collect():
    list1.append(row_iterator['b'])
output:- [4.0, 8.0, 5.0]
time taken:- 0.20 seconds

method2:-
list2 = df.rdd.map(lambda x: x.b).collect()
list2
output:- [4.0, 8.0, 5.0]
time taken:- 0.30 seconds

method3:-
list3 = df.select(df.b).rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()
list3
output:- [4.0, 8.0, 5.0]
time taken:- 0.34 seconds
```

Though iterating over rows is faster but I am looking for a better solution that results faster than this because my pyspark dataframe is huge(10k rows of data). Is there any fastest way of converting pyspark column into a python list?

Comment: This kinda feels like an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you want to convert a huge DF to a list? Maybe there's a better way to get to the end goal than converting it to a list at all.

Comment: Exactly! `collect` is usually an expensive operation. If you have specific transformations to apply, maybe you can try alternatives using native Spark functions.

Comment: Hi, could you check the answers?

Answer (score 0):

There is a function called `collect_list`. Which will only collect **1 column only** instead of the whole data frame like normal collect. As I test on my environment it's quite faster than 3 of your methods. You can test on your environment too.

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import collect_list
import time
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    Row(a=1, b=4., c='GFG1'),
    Row(a=2, b=8., c='GFG2'),
    Row(a=4, b=5., c='GFG3')
]) 

#method 1:-
start_time = time.time()
list1=[]
for row_iterator in df.collect():
    list1.append(row_iterator['b'])
end_time = time.time()
print(end_time - start_time)
#output:- [4.0, 8.0, 5.0]
#time taken:- 7.4 seconds

#method2:-
start_time = time.time()
list2 = df.rdd.map(lambda x: x.b).collect()
end_time = time.time()
print(end_time - start_time)
#output:- [4.0, 8.0, 5.0]
#time taken:- 6.2 seconds

#method3:-
start_time = time.time()
list3 = df.select(df.b).rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()
end_time = time.time()
print(end_time - start_time)
#output:- [4.0, 8.0, 5.0]
#time taken:- 6.1 seconds

#my method (using collect_list):
start_time = time.time()
list4 = df.select(collect_list("b")).first()[0]
end_time = time.time()
print(end_time - start_time)
#output:- [4.0, 8.0, 5.0]
#time taken:- 3.7 seconds
```

Still, it's not advised to use any kind of collect method, because you won't benefit from Spark's parallel processing feature.

Answer (score 0):

Try one of this

```
from pyspark.sql import Row

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    Row(a=1, b=4., c='GFG1'),
    Row(a=2, b=8., c='GFG2'),
    Row(a=4, b=5., c='GFG3')
])
```

***Method 1:***

```
df.select("a").rdd.map(lambda row: row[0]).collect()
```

***Method 2:***

```
df.rdd.map(lambda row: row.asDict()["a"]).collect()
```

***Output:***

```
[1, 2, 4]
```

Both method takes time around ***0.43 seconds*** and I tried this on Databricks community edition with single node configuration, this can change depends on the cluster you have for data processing.

[image: Databricks community edition cluster configuration]